# Payload file FileListAbsolute.txt does not exist compile error

Tags: c#

Trying to debug this error. The exact error is:

> Error 15  Payload file
>   'C:\svn\myproj\obj\Debug\myproj.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt'
>   does not exist.

It occurs when trying to build my solution in VS2012.

I don't know what this file is, or does, but it is definitely there in the solution. It seems to be an auto-generated file of some sort.

Any explanation for what this error might mean or how to fix it?

The file contains a list of every single file in the solution it would seem.

Comment: Where and when do you get this exception? Is there also some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odds are something got out of sync in the obj folder, which is an intermediate folder where Visual Studio stores things to make builds faster in subsequent runs.

Steps I would try, in this order.

- Clean the project
- Clean your solution.
- Delete the bin and obj folders
- Restart VS
- Reboot.

Comment: Thanks. As I was rebuilding, the file was auto-regenerating ("File has changed outside the editor, reload?") but when I deleted it outright, the solution built. Mysterious!

Answer (score 1):

I used the notepad++'s find in files, the problem was "Data\license.xml", so I deleted it from csproj by double clicking on line(pic) in notepad++'s find results window.

[image: Notepad++]